# Чернобурая лисица

Tags: орфография

Почему в сочетании "чернобурая лисица" слово "чернобурая" пишется слитно?

Answer (score 6):

Вероятно, название чернобурая лисица - чернобурка восходит к сочетанию "чёрный бур".
Бурами в старину называли волков в поселениях, близких к башкирам.( Буре — название некоторых башкирских родов, восходящее к тотему волка). Видимо, окрас этих лисиц делал их похожими на волков, поэтому их и назвали "чернобурами", чернобурками, имея в виду не оттенок цвета, а похожесть на волков. Потом от сущ."чернобур" образовалось прилагательное "чернобурый".